# Dual axes in Tableau with different formulas

Tags: filtering, tableau-api, calculated-field

I would like to display on a single page two different measures for the same data set. Say I have a variable **Back to Back** with two values, 1 and 0. I would like the count of 1s to be multiplied by 4, and the count of 0s to be displayed as is.

I did a shelf calculation for count*4, and added that as a measure, but I can't figure out how to exclude the shelf calculation for the **Back to Back 0s** and exclude the regular count for **Back to Back 1s**.

[image]

In short, I want to keep the top calculation and the very bottom calculation, and lose the two in the middle. But don't know how to exclude only on filtered values for a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two calculated fields.

Count of 1 : `count(if [Back to Back] = 1 then [Back to Back] end) * 4`

Count of 0 : `count(if [Back to Back] = 0 then [Back to Back] end)`

Place these on the Row shelf and make your dual axis chart. http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/dual-axis-bar-chart-multiple-measures